# Multiples Usuarios Django

Tags: django

estoy con una duda tengo que realizar un carrito de compras en Django, el mismo de momento contara con dos niveles o tipos de usuarios:

- Cliente
- Administrador

El **cliente** sera quien pueda comprar revisar sus pedidos/ordenes y registrarse como cliente.

El **Administrador** sera quien previamente pueda cargar los productos,ver pedidos, crear clientes, usuarios.

La pagina se ve algo asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que el cliente al dar click en Ingresar accesa a su login y pueda regresar a esta pantalla y hacer un pedido o ver pedidos anteriores, por otro lado el administrador al dar click en Administrador se redigue a otro login donde accede a una pantalla diferente donde gestiona este sitio:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La parte del administrador la hice con el login por defecto de Django, pero tengo la duda en como hacer el del cliente, deberia hacer algo como esto:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_cliente = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Estoy algo perdido, agradeceria cualquier ayuda..!!

Comment: la cuestion es si en realidad necesitas hacer un login diferente para cada usuario, bien podrias mantener el login que ofrece django y luego sobreescrivir la vista, concretamente en el post asi puedes redirigir el login de acuerdo al tipo de usuario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sin duda tomo como referencia la respuesta de Gerardo Sanchez Hernandez, lo que hice fue reescribir en efecto mi views donde mostraba mi template y validaba que tipo de usuario era y rediriguir a su respectiva view:

```
def ValidarUsuario(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.user.is_staff:
            return redirect('principal:menu_principal')
    return redirect('/')
```

Sin duda algo tan simple, gracias y si alguien tiene alguna sugerencia con gusto la acepto..!!